# CSS Expander with only CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors, noscript

i don't want to flood my visitors display with all news, so i want to use expanders for each news. But i want to support vistors with JavaScript disabled too.
My try:

```
#news > .panel > .panel-heading > .panel-title > .label{
   float: right;
}

#news > .panel > .panel-body {
    display: none;
}

#news > .panel > panel-heading > panel-title > a:visited < .panel-title < .panel-heading <         .panel > .panel-body {
   display: block;
}


        <div id="news" class="tab-pane active">
                {% for announcement in server.announcements.all %}
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title"><a href="#">{{ announcement.title }} </a><span class="label label-default">By {{ announcement.writer.get_username }} at {{ announcement.date_created }}</span></h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">

                            {{ announcement.content|safe_html }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

Comment: You can't target parent elements via child elements in css, so a:visited < .panel-title does nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You need to make some changes

First, you will never (at current CSS3 capablity) be able to get what you desire using pure CSS using the `:visited` psuedo-class for two reasons: (1) the `a` element is not at the sibling level of the `.panel-body`, so it cannot control `.panel-body` through css, and (2) the `:visited` pseudo-class has severe restrictions on what it allows a designer to control ([for privacy reasons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector)).

So what can you do? Use `:target` instead.

But that will (1) limit you to allowing only one news item open at a time, and (2) requires you to set `id` properties on your `.panel-body` elements to match the `href` of the `a` tag controlling it. So you would need html structure like this:

```
<div id="news" class="tab-pane active">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">
                <a href="#Item1">Title 1</a>
                <span class="label label-default">By writer name</span>
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body" id="Item1">            
            Panel 1 body
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where each `a` has a unique `href` that is tied to the `id` of the `.panel-body` of the item. Then you can get the functionality similar to what you seek by this CSS for the display:

```css
#news > .panel > .panel-body {
    display: none;
}
#news > .panel > .panel-body:target  {
   display: block;
}
```

You can see how this works in [**this fiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/5Mxt9/9/), and to see how it would work with multiple news items, take a look at [**this fiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/5Mxt9/10/).

**This solution is only CSS3 compatible, so older browsers with javascript disabled would not be able to see any news items (with javascript you can use that to expand)**

Comment: +1 outstanding solution. I think I may use this in lieu of the JavaScript version.

Comment: @iambriansreed: I noticed your edit. I had only put the selector that changed for the `display: block` setting, but I guess putting the selector for the original hiding may make it more clear, even though that selector and code _did not change from the OP's original post_.

Comment: I like to include a little original code in my answers to help the OP understand where the new code should be written. I have had folks paste solution CSS above their CSS which gets overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

Graceful degradation:
I would show all news in a container with internal scrollbar (constrained in height) as in : **http://jsfiddle.net/Py2HU/1/**

And when JS available would add a Show/Hide button, hide N last news and show/hide them after a click (or add Previous/Next buttons to allow scrolling news one by one)

**CSS**

```
.news-wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="news-wrapper">
    <ul class="news">
        <li class="news-item">Lorem ipsum </li>
        <li class="news-item">Lorem ipsum </li>
        <li class="news-item">Lorem ipsum </li>
        <li class="news-item">Lorem ipsum </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Compatibility: IE7+ and easily with IE6 (as simple as `.ie6 .news-wrapper { height: 400px }` if anyone cares)

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for people who are looking for Single expander only with CSS3.
Bootstrap reference is given only to use Glyph-icons(Up/Down).
[check Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BZPKPZDqUgrIExBvoUWE?p=preview)

**HTML**

```
 <div class="expandercheckbox">
  <input id="e1" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
  <label for="e1" class="expanderheader">Click me to Expand/Collpase</label>
  <div class="expandercontainer">
  I am in container. I am visible. Click above to make be collpase.
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 body{
 padding:50px;
 background: #484848;
 color:#fff;
}
.expandercheckbox input[type="checkbox"] { 
 display: none;
 }
.expandercheckbox .expanderheader {
 cursor: pointer;
 }
.expandercheckbox input[type="checkbox"] + .expanderheader {
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 12px;
 white-space: nowrap;
 user-select:none;
-webkit-user-select:none;
}
.expandercheckbox input[type="checkbox"] + .expanderheader:before {
  content: "\e113";
  display: inline-block;
  font: 14px/1em Glyphicons Halflings;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: -2px 0.25em 0 0;
  padding: 1.5px 3.5px;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: #717171;
  /* Old browsers */
}
.expandercheckbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .expanderheader:before {
  content: "\e114";
  padding: 2.5px;
}
.expandercheckbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .expanderheader:after {
  font-weight: bold;
  color:#000;
}
.expandercontainer{
background:#000;
 padding:15px;
}
.expandercheckbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .expandercontainer {
  display: block;
 }
.expandercheckbox input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) ~ .expandercontainer {
  display: none;
 }
```